# Extract kmeans cluster information using Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've implemented the Apache Spark example at

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/mllib-clustering.html#examples

Here is the source :

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

// Load and parse the data
val data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/kmeans_data.txt")
val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))

// Cluster the data into two classes using KMeans
val numClusters = 2
val numIterations = 20
val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)

// Evaluate clustering by computing Within Set Sum of Squared Errors
val WSSSE = clusters.computeCost(parsedData)
println("Within Set Sum of Squared Errors = " + WSSSE)
```

Using dataset :

```
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.1 0.1 0.1
0.2 0.2 0.2
9.0 9.0 9.0
9.1 9.1 9.1
9.2 9.2 9.2
```

I can extract the cluster centers using :

```
  println(clusters.clusterCenters.apply(0))
   println(clusters.clusterCenters.apply(1))
```

which returns

```
[9.1,9.1,9.1]
[0.10000000000000002,0.10000000000000002,0.10000000000000002]
```

But there are some items I'm not sure of, which does not seem to be supported by the API :

How can I extract what points have been added to each of the two clusters ?

How to add labels to each data point so that while viewing what points are in each cluster can also determine each points label ? Do I need to update the Spark Kmeans implementation to achieve this ?

Comment: In the first question, are you referring to the _vectors_ that make up your rows? or the actual points within the vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using java,

```
javaRDD cluster_indices = clusters.predict(parsedData);
```

as predict is overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The method that you are looking for is *predict()* but does not belong to *KMeans.scala*. Is part of the class *KMeansModel.scala* (which is the return type of *KMeans.train(...)* )

The use would be:

```
    clusters.predict(data_to_cluster)
```